# Is there a way to generate n differentiable instances of a class using a loop?

Tags: java

I want to asign data, that I previously read from a simple "backup" text file (txt), to n differentiable instances of a class so that I can use those instances later on. Is there a way to achieve this using some kind of loop?

I tried creating multiple instances c_0, c_1, .. , c_n of a class "Category" which store the "category name" from the corresponding line in a txt file. A line from that file starts with the category name followed by a comma and negligible information. Now I want to have n (= amount of lines) different Category instances every time I call this function in the beginning of the script. Up till now I tried the following:

```
public class Backup{
static int maxC = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        readC();
    }
    public static class Category{
        private String categoryName;
        public Category(String nameC){
            categoryName = nameC;
        }
    }
    private static void readC(){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String seperate = ",";
        int i = 0;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Public/Category.txt"));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] oneLineArray = line.split(seperate);
                Category c_i = new Category(oneLineArray[0]); //I have a strong feeling
                //that this only creates c_i and not the c_0 c_1 that I would want here
                //How can one achieve that?
                i++;
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File does not exist. "+e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O Error. "+e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if (br != null){
                try{
                br.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("I/O Error. "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        maxC = i-1; //this is the amount (n) of instances created
    }
```

}

Like I said, I expected to have multiple instances but i kinda suspect every  cycle of the loop is just `c_i` and not `c_0` etc. Can someone enlighten me? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you need to use arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c_i` is just the variable name, `i` there is just a character like `c` or `_`.

You want to create either an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html). [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) collection is the easiest choice, it will store all new objects and dynamical adjust size.

```
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    String[] oneLineArray = line.split(seperate);
    Category c = new Category(oneLineArray[0]);
    categories.add(c);
}
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what I was about to answer!

Comment: When I try your approach I get the: "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments" error. What do I do?

Comment: @FritzWalter are you using `java.util.List` or some other `List`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Oh, sorry my fault. I had a typo. Instead of a point I accidentally used a comma.